# SQL- Retrieve records based on column's specific value

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables with below info

Table# 1 - TaskDependecy

| TaskID | DependentTaskID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 5 | 8 |

Table # 2 - TaskStatus

| TaskID | Task Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | In Progress |
| 2 | Completed |
| 3 | In Progress |
| 5 | In Progress |
| 6 | Completed |
| 7 | Completed |
| 8 | Completed |

I want to retrieve only taskIDs # 3 and 5 so that I can update status of these taskIDs as Completed since all its dependent tasks are in completed status.

How to achieve this in SQL?

Comment: What RDBMS are you *really* using? SQL Server and MySQL are *completely* different products.

Comment: It is mySQL in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `conditional aggregation` for this, which should work in either MSSQL or MySQL

```
select td.taskId
from TaskDependency td
join TaskStatus ts on ts.taskId = td.DependentTaskId
group by td.TaskId
having Sum(case when ts.TaskStatus='completed' then 1 end) = Count(*)
```

[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdcb7a/1)